# Accessible travel by Tube from Heathrow to Kings Cross

Tags: airport-transfer, lhr, accessibility, tfl

I understand the Tube is the best way to get from Heathrow to Kings Cross.  Does this journey have escalators and lifts all the way? I am unable to carry my cases.

Comment: Depending on the time of day, you will have to fight your way on and off a tube due to the number of people, and other users will expect you to hold your case up, so it does not take up floor space they could be standing on.

Comment: @IanRingrose: at least if the OP has any visible reason for their difficulty with carrying cases (e.g. elderly, arm in a sling, in a wheelchair, etc.), commuters will usually be tolerant of them taking up a bit more space.

Comment: The Tube map shows accessibility - stations with "step free access" are marked with a wheelchair symbol (white if you can reach the platform with no steps, but there's a gap you might need help with to get onto the train, blue if there are no steps even onto the train itself)

Comment: I wouldn't say the tube is the best - probably a taxi is the best, especially if you have trouble with cases - the tube is cramped, accessibility notwithstanding. But a taxi is, of course, expensive.

Answer (score 15):

What you want here is the [Avoiding stairs Tube guide](http://content.tfl.gov.uk/avoiding-stairs-tube-guide.pdf), linked from the [TfL](http://tfl.gov.uk) [Accessibility guides](http://tfl.gov.uk/forms/12387.aspx) page.

In this guide you will see that all the Heathrow stations, as well as King’s Cross St. Pancras, are marked with **Lift access between street and platform**, and additionally all have the **Platforms with designated level access boarding point** indication, which means that at certain points along the train there will be level access all the way onto the train (so you won't have to step up or down).

You will be able to wheel your cases the whole way.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, there are a few stairs which separate the platform from the ticketing area at King's Cross. This is not to say that there are no elevators: I wouldn't know since I never looked for them. Could you please check if I am mistaken?

Comment: IIRC There is an additional lift round the side to avoid those stairs. As you approach the southern escalators down to the deep-level tube lines, it's on your far left

Comment: @JoErNanO since the most recent upgrade, there are elevators alongside almost all stairs, and alternative routes when there aren't. I've found a nice WebGL version [here](http://stations.aeracode.org/#kxx)

Comment: I think you'll be ok on that particular route.  But, if you're not carrying too many cases, don't feel excluded from any route.  Other more able-bodied travellers are very helpful!

Comment: The gap between the trains and the platform is often too large to wheel a case over.

Comment: @IanRingrose true, although no more than 85mm at the stations in question.

Comment: It could be that the OP is wheelchair-bound, and not just traveling with heavy luggage.

Comment: @JoErNanO the lifts from the Piccadilly line take you to the new ticket hall which doesn't have those steps in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Just looked it up on [Transport for London's Journey Planner for Heathrow to King's Cross with **Full step free access**](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&InputFrom=Heathrow%20Airport%20Terminals%201-3&From=Heathrow%20Airport%20Terminals%201-3&FromId=1000105&PreviousFrom=&InputTo=King%27s%20Cross%20&%20St%20Pancras%20International&To=King%27s%20Cross%20&%20St%20Pancras%20International&ToId=1000129&PreviousTo=&Date=20160302&Time=1200&WalkingSpeedWalking=average&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&WalkingSpeedTransport=average&InputVia=&DataSetsJson=[["stopPoints","journeyPlannerNoSubmit?Input=%7B%7Binput%7D%7D"]]&Via=&ViaId=&PreviousVia=&NationalSearch=false&WalkingOptimization=false&SavePreferences=false&IsPastWarning=False&JourneyPreference=leasttime&mode=bus&mode=tube&mode=tflrail&mode=tram&mode=overground&mode=dlr&mode=cable-car&mode=river-bus&mode=national-rail&mode=coach&JpType=publictransport&CyclePreference=none&AccessibilityPreference=stepfreetovehicle&iscyclehire=false&isMultipleJourneySelection=true&journeytype=Full%20step%20free%20access&useMultiModalCall=false&isEarlierLaterAjaxCall=false) and TfL recommends taking the Heathrow Express to Paddington and then the Circle Line to King's Cross. Without **Full step free access** TfL recommends taking the tube straight to King's Cross via the Piccadilly line.

Comment: This is an expensive option.

Comment: @Ian I agree, just passing on TfL's advise on the matter.

Comment: This is what I did (Travelling with two cases and two toddlers).  Of course, for me it wasn't an expensive option, because I had bought anyway a BritRail pass which made the Heathrow Express free.

Comment: I think it's only showing it because it's theoretically faster. If you exclude National Rail from the options you get shown the Piccadilly line route: https://t.co/Ht0zhvMsz6

Comment: @Ganesh If you change it from 'fastest route' to 'route with fewest changes' you get the Piccadilly line also. http://tinyurl.com/hqryzlv